# why polymorphism not applicable with generics?

Tags: java, generics

what is the problem with the below code

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    static class Car {}
    static class bmw extends Car{}

    List<Car> list = new LinkedList<bmw>();
}
```

Complier shows the following error:

```
Test.java:7: error: incompatible types: LinkedList<bmw> cannot be converted to List<Car>
    List<Car> list = new LinkedList<bmw>();
                     ^
```

Why it does not work?

Comment: Please post more code. [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: simple you cannot do this list has to be of one type you can do this List<Car> list = new LinkedList<Car>(); then list.add(new bmw());

Comment: please help me with this

Answer (score 2):

It's applicable when you write

```
List<? extends Car> list = new LinkedList<bmw>();
```

When you declare `List<Car> list`, you can put any car in the resulting `list` (not just `bmw`). So `List<Car>` is not a `List<bmw>` as it allows to do something which is incompatible with `List<bmw>`. Suppose you have

```
List<Bmw> bmwList = new LinkedList<Bmw>();
List<Car> carList = bmwList; // let's assume this works as you want
carList.add(new Audi()); // works normally: you can put Audi into the list of cars
    // so our bmwList becomes broken here
Bmw bmw = bmwList.get(0); // this should work as we have list of BMW, 
    // but we suddenly got an Audi!
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a `List` of Car means it will hold all the instances of `Car`,

- `Your bmw is a Car`
- but your `Car is not bmw`

  so if you want to insert `bmw` in list of `Car` you can easily, but if you want to insert all the classes `extending` Car then you can use the approach Tagir mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to Tagir's answer: JVM does a process called 'Type Erasure' at runtime.

This means; your original list

```
List<Car> list = new LinkedList<bmw>();
```

Becomes

```
List list = new LinkedList();
```

at runtime. To maintain type safety at runtime, compiler takes precaution and perform static type checking when using generics.